# Presentation of $A_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In my book, it states that $\langle a, b | a^3 = b^2 = 1, aba = ba^2 b  \rangle$ is a presentation of $A_4$. I am having trouble working out the details though. I know that $A_4$ is generated by 3-cycles, but I'm not sure if that is relevant. I tried manipulating the generators algebraically, but also wasn't able to show that it is a presentation of $A_4.$

Comment: Given $b^2 = 1$ I would guess that $b$ must be something like $(1 2) (3 4)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different approach.

Here is a picture, of the different multiplications.
We move along the black lines if we multiply the right side by $a$  I have used $a'$ to represent $a^2 = a^{-1}$.  And we move along the red lines when we multiply by $b$ (on the right).

[image]

And playing with this a little bit you should come to the conclusion that it is indeed closed, and that every element has an inverse.  Hence this is a group.

original approach

If you map $a = (123)$
and $b = (12)(34)$ these two elements meet the criteria of your group and they indeed generate $A_4$

Is this the "largest group."

There can really be only one group generated by some set of generators.  Once you have generate a group, it is closed to any further operations.  If you multiply the elements by one of the generators, you get an element you have already found.

Comment: Thanks, that makes so much sense! But could you tell me how you know that this is the largest group generated by this presentation? Is there some way to write an product with all of the $a$'s before the $b$'s for example?

Comment: I have given you something else to think about.

Comment: But how do we know that, say, $S_4$ doesn't also satisfy all of the relations given for the generators?

Comment: All of these elements are in $S_4$, but you can't get from $A_4$ to $S_4$ without introducing an additional generator.     Once we have these 12 elements.  If we multiply by our generators, in any order, it will simplify to one of the 12 we already have.

Comment: Thanks, now I see.